# Cordova iOS 6.2.0 local iFrame

Tags: ios, http, cordova, iframe, wkwebview

I'm tasked with porting a web app over to an iPad app using Cordova. I have everything functioning properly except a bunch of local iframes that are embedded within the app and need to be served over http in order to function.

In the web app, the solution is simple - upload them to a server and then use url as the iframe src. However I am tasked with bundling everything locally for a client's offline iPad app - the iframes do not load the content without being served over http and using file:// to try and access the resources does not work. Where/how should I look to serve these resources locally so I can access them within an app without getting a blank screen?

I've read a whole bunch about WkWebView being deprecated, Cordova changing the way everything works for serving local files within an app and I'm just plain lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [cordova-plugin-ios-xhr](https://github.com/globules-io/cordova-plugin-ios-xhr) and set

```
<preference name="allowFileAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
<preference name="allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs" value="true" />
```

for files to work with `file://`